# Polymorphic paperclip model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphism, paperclip

I am setting up a model called `Wall` which has many `Assets`.  The assets model is a paperclip model.  Everything seems to be ok but it will not render the form.  In the `walls controller` I am building 5 assets with the line `5.times { @wall.assets.build }`.  The line `ap @wall.assets.build` spits out 5 asset records in the console fine. I have included the code below.  I cannot see what I have done wrong.  Anyone have any idea?

wall.rb

```
class Wall < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

asset.rb

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :assetable_id, :assetable_type
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

walls_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @wall = Wall.new
    5.times do
      @wall.assets.build
    end
    ap @wall.assets
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @wall }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @wall = Wall.find(params[:id])
    5.times do
      @wall.assets.build
    end
  end
```

_form.html.haml

```
= form_for @wall, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => true } do |f|
  .control-group
    = f.label :name, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field'
  - f.fields_for :assets do |asset|
    = asset.file_field :asset
  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), walls_path, :class => 'btn'
```

Cheers

Tony

Comment: I noticed the problem.  I was using - instead of = in front of the form for

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer, than mark it as accepted.